# WoW Armory APi - Can't get Title

Tags: javascript, rest, world-of-warcraft

Hello I'm trying to pull my characters title from the Warcraft Armory but I don't get any returned results.  My code is as follows with my character name being replaced with my actual character name .

HTML

```
<li>Title Prefix: <span id="title">Test</span>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).load(function getSite(){
            $.ajax({                
                url: "http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/server/character?fields=titles&jsonp=GoGet",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                });
            }

        );  

        function GoGet(data) {


            $("#title").html(data.titles.name)              
        ;}
```

The api documentation shows the json items for "titles" as follows:

```
{
"achievementPoints": 675,
"battlegroup": "Test Battlegroup",
"calcClass": "f",
"class": 10,
"gender": 1,
"lastModified": 1348187981118,
"level": 90,
"name": "Peratryn",
"race": 25,
"realm": "Test Realm",
"thumbnail": "test-realm/1/1-avatar.jpg",
"titles": [
    {
    "id": 285,
    "name": "%s, Savior of Azeroth",
    "selected": true
    }
    ]
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What did you get back from the server?

Comment: A full list of titles plus my selected one, I just can't get my code to spit it out.

Comment: `titles` looks like an array.

Answer (score 3):

Not being a WOW player myself, I'll hazard one guess:

```
        $(window).load(function getSite(){
            $.ajax({                
                url: "http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/server/character?fields=titles&jsonp=GoGet",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: UpdateTitle
                });
            }

        );  

        function UpdateTitle(response) {
            if (response.titles) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.titles.length; i++) {
                  if (response.titles[i].selected === true) {
                      $("#title").html(response.titles[i].name);
                      break;
                  }
                }
            }                  
        }
```

What this is doing is calling `UpdateTitle` after a successful XHR response from your provided URL.  This function will loop through each title and update your `#title` element with the FIRST `selected: true` title found in the json response.

Comment: Hah, good call.  Updated to include index 0.  Obviously Yanayaya can do something smarter with lists, checking for data, etc.

Comment: Thanks this works if you know the title you are trying to select, you simply change the value however I need to pick the title that has been selected, can this be done by access the "selected: true" resource?

Comment: Updated to check selected property.

Comment: Thanks for making that change for me however now it returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the amendment there is however a new issue.  FireBug shows that the returned json is missing ; before statement. SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"lastModified": <--- line 1 col 15

I'm not sure what that's about as I can't actually adjust the received data from the resource.